# lektor live server not pushing the changes to the browser

Tags: lektor

Many other testing http server like some available for VScode, Atom, Hugo etcetera are "live" server. I mean that as soon as I save a file the change appears in the browser.

With Lektor I have to make my changes (say some content, or the css) then go to the browser window and *refresh* the page. Actually when I change anything (*just typing, without even saving!*) I see that the involved pages are regenerated (pruned), but the changes are not pushed to the browser (lektor 3.2.0 + firefox on win10 in my case).

Am I missing some configuration? On the browser side eventually?

Thank you

Comment: Not familiar specifically with Lektor, but the other things you mentioned do 'hot-reloading' which means that they inject some code into the browser that waits for a message from your development server to reload. It could be that "Lektor" does not support this, or maybe you missing a configuration. Have you looked at documentation?

Comment: @asosnovsky Yes I checked, and did'nt find anything, that's why I'm asking here. 
Lektor is written in python. Is there maybe a library that does that to easilly implement it?

Comment: this does not sound like the place to ask for this. If you can't find anything in their docs and there is no plugin for this. It might just not be a thing. Try to submit an issue to their repo or email the owners of the library.

Comment: @asosnovsky on the website they send here for help and questions. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Lektor does not support hot-reloading as already said in the comments. And to clarify your statement, you said Lektor does reload pages after you type something, even before it is saved. That is not correct, or at least a coincidence. Yes, Lektor does indeed sometimes prune without you changing a file. But it was (most likely) not triggered by your typing. Lektor only re-generates affected files after you save a file.